# Having trouble with writing a simple python password reset code sample

Tags: python, csv, directory, set

I'm new to Python and trying to wirte a simple password reset code sample to learn about sets, dictionaries, and exception handlers. To reset a password, the program must first take in both the student_id and user_id and confirms their ID against the list. If the student_id and user_id match, it will prompt the user for their admission term as an extra security measure. If all things match, the program will greet the user by name and prompt their to enter their new password. The new password cannot match any of the user's previous passwords. The program should not quit until the user asks to quit or successfully logs in (note, resetting the password should not be the end and we may give the user a "quit" option if they decide they do not want to change their password.).

The program should run similar to the following:

```
1. Login
2. Reset Password
3. Quit
What would you like to do?  1
User Name: afrank
Password: xyz123
Login Success!

------------------------------------------------
1. Login
2. Reset Password
3. Quit
What would you like to do? 1
User Name: afrank
Password: xyz1234
Incorrect Password
1. Login
2. Reset Password
3. Quit
What would you like to do? 3

------------------------------------------------
1. Login
2. Reset Password
3. Quit
What would you like to do? 2
Student ID: 392111111
User Name: afrank
What year were you admitted? 2018
New Password: abc456
Confirm New Password: abc456
Password Changed!
1. Login
2. Reset Password
3. Quit
What would you like to do? 3


------------------------------------------------
1. Login
2. Reset Password
3. Quit
What would you like to do? 2
Student ID: afrank
Error! Please enter your Student ID Number.
Student ID: 39211111x
Error! Please enter your Student ID Number.
Student ID: 39211111111
Error! Student ID Not Found
Student ID: 392111111
User Name: afrank
What year were you admitted? 2018
New Password: abc456
Confirm New Password: abc456
Password Changed!
1. Login
2. Reset Password
3. Quit
What would you like to do? 3

------------------------------------------------
1. Login
2. Reset Password
3. Quit
What would you like to do? 2
Student ID: 392111111
User Name: afrank
What year were you admitted? 2018
New Password: 123abc
Confirm New Password: 123abc
Error. Your password cannot be a previously used password.
New Password: abc456
Confirm New Password: abc456
1. Login
2. Reset Password
3. Quit
What would you like to do? 1
User Name: afrank
Password: abc456
Login Success!
```

[image: student_password.csv]

I worte a few pieces but I have no idea how to continue:

```
idfile = open('student_password.csv', 'r')     ## Read in Current File
header = idfile.readline()
allobs = idfile.readlines()
namedict = {}
userdict = {}
termdict = {}
pwdict = {}
p_pwdict = {}
for obs in allobs:
    obslist=obs.split(",")
    namedict2 = {int(obslist[0]): (obslist[1], obslist[2])}
    userdict2 = {int(obslist[0]): obslist[3]}
    termdict2 = {int(obslist[0]): int(obslist[4])}
    pwdict2 = {int(obslist[0]): obslist[5]}
    p_pwdict2 = {int(obslist[0]): obslist[6].replace('\n', '')}
    namedict.update(namedict2)
    userdict.update(userdict2)
    termdict.update(termdict2)
    pwdict.update(pwdict2)
    p_pwdict.update(p_pwdict2)
idfile.close()

result = input(' 1. Login \n 2. Reset Password \n 3. Quit \n What would you like to do? \n ')

if result == '1':
...
```

Comment: nowadays no one use csv for password storage , all uses databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a real code. A real login code should include a lot more, like securing channels, ecryption, etc.
As an exercise to try a few concepts it's ok.

I see you are expecting to save everything to a file, I suggest you to try with logical structures first.
There is always messing with opened files not being able to be updated and the like. 
Another recommendation is to keep distinct functions to distinct funcionalities, is easier to maintain and to debug.

I see a perfect use for dictionary, with key (login) and value (password).
Would be good to create a class and put options_menu() in main function.

```
dict_logs = {'afrank':'xyz123','lcroft':'xpto0007','happy_bird':'123abc'}

#check name and password are in a dictionary
def hello_login():

    isUser = False #start as False

    print('What is your user name?')
    user = str(input())

    for u,p in dict_logs.items():

        if u == user:
            dictpass  = p
            isUser    = True
    if isUser:
        print('Enter password')
        password = str(input())
        if dictpass == password:
            print('Login Success!')
        else:
            print('Error: wrong password')
            options_menu() 
    else:
        print('Error: wrong user name')
        options_menu()


user_info = {392111111:['afrank',2018],392111131:['lcroft',2018],392113005:['happy_bird',2019]}         

# check if information is in a dictionary and updates another dict  
def reset_password():

    isUser  = False #start as False
    changed = False #start as False

    print('What is your student ID?')
    sid = int(input())

    for ui,data in user_info.items():

        if ui == sid:
            checksOn = data
            isUser = True

    if isUser:

        print('What is your user name?')
        uname   = str(input())  #accept parameter user_name

        if checksOn[0] == uname:
            print('What year were you admitted?')
            year = int(input())  #accept parameter year of admission

            if checksOn[1] == year:

                while not changed: #loop if changed not True
                    print('Enter a new password')   
                    newPass = str(input()) #accept parameter password

                    if dict_logs[uname] != newPass: #must be distinct of saved password             
                        print('Confirm password')
                        confPass = str(input())

                        if confPass == newPass:     #confirmation ok
                            dict_logs.update({uname:confPass})
                            changed = True
                            print('Password changed!')
                        else:
                            print('Error:passwords are distincts!')
                    else:
                        print('Error. Your password cannot be a previously used password.')

            else:
                print('Error. Year of addmission is wrong')
        else:
            print('Error. User name is wrong')
    else:
        print('Error! Please enter your Student ID Number')


# menu of options   
def options_menu():

    print('1. Login'+'\n'+'2. Reset Password'+'\n'+'3. Quit'+'\n'+'What would you like to do?')
    option = int(input())

    if option == 1:

        hello_login()

    elif option == 2:

        reset_password()

    elif option == 3:

        pass
```

Comment: Thx bro, now I understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so quick disclaimer all the code in this is sudo code and is for example to give you the idea of my train of thought.

So that out of the way I see your problems as the following.

- User Input (Actions)
- DataBase Handling

If I am correct on this I would suggest that you take the following approach.

1. Take care of the Database, by writing a class to handle the getting and setting of specific user in an out of the database that you are using and into a dictionary or any other data structure allows you to forget the structure of the underlying csv etc and will make you actions clearer and simpler later on. something like below would do the trick.

   ```
   class UserDataBase(object):

       def __init__(self):
           self.database = db

       def get_user(self, username) -> dict:
           return {"Joe": {"password": "uber_secret"}}

       def set_user(self, username, user_obj: dict) -> None:
           db[username] = user_obj
   ```
2. Next it would be time to take care of the user input, again this should be an object that would define and execute the actions that you define in your use cases.

   ```
   class Actions(object):

       def __init__(self, database):
           self.database = UserDataBase()

       def login(self, username, password) -> bool:
            if self.database.get_user(username) == password:
                   return True
            return False

       def reset_password(self, old_password, new_password, confirmed_password) -> bool:
           reset_code

       def quit(self):
           quit()
   ```

This would then leave you with two objects that you can tie together to get anything that you want to do done more simply.

```
def get_input():

    actions = Actions(
        database=UserDataBase()
    )
    i = input(' 1. Login \n 2. Reset Password \n 3. Quit \n What would you like to do? \n ')

    if i == 1:
        actions.login(username=input('username: '), password=input('password: '))

get_input()
```

if you have any specific questions about this approach please let me know.